# using preset themes in R: possibility to change parameters?

Tags: r, themes

Let's say I want to plot this:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=rownames(d),group=1)) +       
  geom_line(aes(y = y2, color = "y2")) +
    theme(
    plot.title = element_text(color="gray50"),
    legend.title=element_blank())
```

By using the `theme_minimal()`.
I notice if I replace theme( by `theme_minimal(` it won't work (tells me there are unused arguments). Is there a quick way to use parameters from a predefined theme that are not defined in the current `theme()`?

Comment: Please study the help text (before asking). The second sentence in `?theme_minimal`: "Use `theme()` if you just need to tweak the display of an existing theme."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a theme like `theme_minimal` and then modify its parameters with `theme`, so

```r
ggplot(d, aes(x=rownames(d),group=1)) +       
  geom_line(aes(y = y2, color = "y2")) +
  theme_minimal() +
    theme(
    plot.title = element_text(color="gray50"),
    legend.title=element_blank())
```